# Uncertainty about the definition of entail

Tags: propositional-calculus

> Definition
> We say that a set of propositions (the "premises") $Γ$ entails a proposition $φ$ (the "conclusion") if for every truth assignment $A$, if $A(φ)$=1 when we have $A(ψ)$=1 for all $\psi$ in $Γ$.
>
> Note: if a truth assignment assigns "false" (i.e. 0) to a premise in $Γ$, it doesn't matter what it assigns to $φ$; this truth assignment still satisfies the definition.

The note below makes me confuse. Does it mean if there exists $A(ψ)$=0 for $\psi$ in $Γ$, $Γ$ entails $φ$ still hold?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition must be rephrased as :

> there are **no** truth assignment $A$ such that : $A(\psi)=1$ for every $\psi \in \Gamma$ and $A(\varphi)=0$.

Thus, what happens with a truth assignment $A'$ that assigns "false" (i.e. $0$) to some premise $\psi \in \Gamma$ ?

It doesn't matter what they "do" to $\varphi$, because we are only concerned with the truth assignements that "satisfy" (i.e. assign $1$) to **all** $\psi \in \Gamma$.

---

You must read the definition as a "recipe" to test for *entailment* :

*(i)* consider a truth assignement $A$ : are all formulae $\psi$ in $\Gamma$ *true* for $A$ ?

- If NO, skip it (i.e. skip $A$).
- If YES, then check if $\varphi$ is true.

*(ii)* if $\varphi$ is true for $A$, then take a new truth assignment $A'$ and go to step *(i)*.

*(iii)* if $\varphi$ is false for $A$, then stop : $\varphi$ is **not** entailed by $\Gamma$.

Comment: After rephrasing the definition, it means if $A(ψ)$=1  for every $ψ$∈$Γ$, then $A(φ)$ must be 1. Am I correct?

Comment: I still don't get it. What happen if there exists A(ψ) =0 for ψ∈Γ?

Comment: @yashirq - Comment 1 : CORRECT.

Comment: @yashirq - Comment 2 : following comment 1, if the *antecedent* of the conditional is *false* (because if for some $\psi \in \Gamma$ : $A'(\psi)=0$, we have that "$A'(\psi)=1$, for every $\psi \in \Gamma$" is *false*), then the conditional is *true*. This means that in this case the "statement" expressing the definition of *entailment* is satisfied. See [vacuous truth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth).

Comment: Not quite get what you mean by saying the antecedent of the conditional is false then the conditional is true. I have some new understanding. If we have A$(ψ)$ =0, then the condition is false. But both 0 -> 0 and 0 -> 1 are true. So we don't care about what A$(φ)$ is.

Comment: @yashirq - see [Truth table for conditional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_conditional#Truth_table).